# Why the JupyterHub kernel does not align with kernel.json?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am using DockerSpawner's SystemUserSpawner (https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner) to spawn docker containers to run notebooks in.

The Jupyter in those containers is running on Python 3 and now I am trying to add a Python 2 kernel to it.

```
RUN pip3.6 --no-cache install \
    jupyterhub==0.9.0 \
    'notebook>=5.0,<=6.0'
...
RUN python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python2 -m pip --no-cache install 'ipython<6'
RUN python2 -m pip --no-cache install ipykernel
```

After this the Python 2 kernel does show up in the list in Jupyter - as it is supposed to -, but it is actually running Python 3 inside it when I start it and run the following in the 'Python 2' notebook to verify the 'real' version:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

3.6.5 (default, Apr 10 2018, 17:08:37) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
```

Looking at the available kernels in this container, everything seems good:

```
[zoltan.fedor@7a30bb98f7c0 ~]$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2    /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

But actual the kernel files are identical (with the exception of the title):

```
vi /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json
-----
{
 "display_name": "Python 2",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

And the Python 3 one:

```
vi /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
----
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Simply running 'python' brings up Python 2 - as it should:

```
[zoltan.fedor@7a30bb98f7c0 ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So why both of these kernels are running Python 3 in them? If something, then I would see them both running python 2, as they use "python" as the "argv", which should start python 2.7.5 and not 3.6.5.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue simply was that I forgot to run the following.

```
RUN python2 -m ipykernel install
```

The strange thing, that the python2 kernel.json was created even without this, it was just not set to execute python 2.
After this the python2 kernel was now pointing to:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3    /usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

The kernel.json's content was:

```
$ vi /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json
----
{
 "display_name": "Python 2",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python2",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

Now this really is a python 2 kernel.